# Logging stdout while interpreting newlines

Tags: python, subprocess

I am calling a system program from my script using `subprocess.Popen`, and capturing the `stdout` and `stderr` in a log file. However, all of the returned info is on a single line with `\n` and `\t` characters not interpreted. Is there a module to wrap those in my log file?

```
import logging
import subprocess as sp

# build list for cmd
logging.info('Command to run: {}'.format(cmd_list))
cmd = sp.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()
logging.info(stdout)
# output is INFO:root:b"Welcome to MAGMA v1.07b (linux/s)\nUsing flags:\n\t--annotate...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python logged `str(stdout)`, but `stdout` is a byte stream so you got the whole `bytes` representation starting with `b'` and backslash escaped newlines. You need to decode it first. Using the default encoding on your system should work

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig()
>>> import subprocess as subp
>>> cmd = subp.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.STDOUT)
>>> stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate()
>>> logging.warning(stdout)
```

WARNING:root:b'a.py\nb.py\nc.py\ne.py\nf.py\ng.py\nh.py\ni.py\nj.py\nl.py\n__pycache__\n'

```
>>> logging.warning(stdout.decode())
WARNING:root:a.py
b.py
c.py
e.py
f.py
g.py
h.py
i.py
j.py
l.py
__pycache__
```